# How to enable IntelliSense for C++ in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I've just installed VS2015 for C++ development, however traditional hot keys like `ctrl+space` or `.` or `->` don't show the IntelliSense window.
Somewhere on the web I found that I needed to open the IntelliSense Manager from the Tools menu. But that's not in my Tools window.

In addition, I reviewed related items in my IDE settings and found a `Text Editor -> C++ -> Advanced - IntelliSense` section with a number of settings, including Disable IntelliSense, which is `True` in my setup. The problem is that all settings in this section are readonly (not editable).

How do I fix the problem?

VS2015.2, fresh install. No previous installation on this host.

Comment: VS2015 by default does not install C++ support, it has to be manually enabled during installation. maybe it's related to that?

Comment: no, i've installed vc++, and the solution was built with no issues

Comment: Interesting.  All of my options in that same menu are enabled and disbale intellisens is set to false.  What version of VS2015 do you have?  I have Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL

Comment: VS2015 community update 2 14.0.25123.0

Comment: Have you tried the solutions suggested here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-resolve-intellisense-issue-in-visual-studio1

Comment: tried this for now, one-by-one, in parallel , removed all stuff in AppData related with VS, lost my configs but not a problem - this was today installation, real start the parsing of headers (it was not performed and I didn't know how to initialize this, and probably it was a reason of no tips ) was started after List of Members point in Edit | IntelliSense thank you!!

Comment: There's another technique that may be useful if you have this problem again: from a VS command prompt run `devenv /resetide` which will reset your user settings.